# Inverse of a large sparse Hermitian block matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I am looking for a method (if it exists) for the inverse of a large sparse Hermitian block matrix.
The off diagonal sparse matrices, named `δ` are 4x4, and they have only one non null element on the diagonal part. The matrices `M` are Hermitian and also 4x4. I need a way to perform the inverse of `M3` or the determinant. I am interested in a generalization of this structure for a matrix of higher rank with the same "telescopic" structure.
Here is the code

```
dimension        = 4;
mat              = ( {{m, a, b, b},{Conjugate[a], m, b, b},{Conjugate[b], Conjugate[b], m, a},{Conjugate[b], Conjugate[b], Conjugate[a], m}});
Subscript[O, 4]  = ( {{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0}} );
Subscript[δ, 1]  = ( {{I ρ, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0}} );
Subscript[δ, 2]  = ( {{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, I ρ, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0}} );
Subscript[δ, 3]  = ( {{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, I ρ, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0}} );
Subscript[δ, 4]  = ( {{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, 0},{0, 0, 0, I ρ}} );
Subscript[δ, 22] = ArrayFlatten[( {{Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[δ, 2]}, {Subscript[δ, 2], Subscript[O, 4]}})];
Subscript[δ, 33] = ArrayFlatten[( {
    {Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[δ, 3]},
    {Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[δ, 3], Subscript[O, 4]},
    {Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[δ, 3], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4]},
    {Subscript[δ, 3], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4]}
} )];
Subscript[δ, 44] = ArrayFlatten[( {
    {Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[δ, 4]},
    {Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[δ, 4], Subscript[O, 4]},
    {Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[δ, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4]}, 
    {Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[δ, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4]}, 
    {Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[δ, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4]},
    {Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[δ, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4]},
    {Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[δ, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4]},
    {Subscript[δ, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4], Subscript[O, 4]}
} )];

OutM[M_, δ_] := ArrayFlatten[{{M, δ},{-δ, M}}];
M1 = OutM[mat, Subscript[δ, 1]];
M2 = FullSimplify[OutM[M1, Subscript[δ, 22]]];
M3 = FullSimplify[OutM[M2, Subscript[δ, 33]]];
M4 = FullSimplify[OutM[M3, Subscript[δ, 44]]];
```

And I need the inverse of `M4`. The structure is telescopic in some sense.

Comment: Even better, could you provide code to construct it so we don't have to re-write it?

Comment: You are aware that inverting a large, sparse matrix invariably results in a **large, dense** matrix, right? Or do you have any guarantee that the inverse has a known/predictable sparsity pattern?

Comment: If the matrix isn't too big, what exactly is the problem with using `Inverse[]`/`Det[]` directly?

Comment: i wrote the structure again. When I raise up the rank of this kind of matrices mathematica is not able to perform the inverse. I need some tip in order to use the sparsity....

Comment: I think there's an error in your definition of `OutM`. A bracket and a comma are missing. I presume it should be `OutM[M_, \[Delta]_] := ArrayFlatten[( {{M, \[Delta]},{-\[Delta], M}} )];`

Comment: I don't see the problem. On my laptop MMA finds the `Inverse` of M1, M2, M3, M4 in 0.01, 0.4, 5, and 66 seconds, respectively.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, interesting - MMA 8.0.4 on my Core i5 machine takes 0.04s for `Inverse[M1]`, 9 seconds for `Inverse[M2]` and I aborted `Inverse[M3]` after 5 minutes.

Comment: I have a Core i7, and I see MMA use 3 or 4 of the 8 hyperthreaded cores. That might make a difference. Did you use the same correction as I did (see comment above)?

Comment: OutM[M_, \[Delta]_] := ArrayFlatten[( {
     {M, \[Delta]},
     {-\[Delta], M}
    } )];

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries if you can please send me the computation of the inverse at my address ozellus@gmail.com. Thank you

Comment: @SimonWoods and Raffaele: I was trying to repeat what I did before and it didn't work out the same way. I had been working on [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6092/animate-a-position-change-along-the-curve-for-every-iteration) which resulted in a and b already being defined as a numerical value. Now, with a and b symbolic, MMA indeed runs into problems. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: in fact i am using your same cpu configuration and the result is not coming out.

Comment: Here's a [related question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8/how-to-symbolically-do-matrix-block-inversion). The approach to block-inversion discussed in Daniel Lichtblau's answer should work here.